# help with vector calculus

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

the question is :
how do I prove that:   $\nabla^2 (r^n\vec r)=n(n+3)r^{n-2}\vec r$

Comment: What are $r$ and $\textbf{r}$ ?

Comment: What exactly is $r$? What have you tried? You should explain the problem a bit more and show any work you have done.

Comment: @Zubzub $\vec r=(x,y,z)$ and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Use
>   $\ds{\quad\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
> \ds{\nabla^{2}\pars{ab}} & \ds{=} & \ds{b\nabla^{2}a + 2\nabla a\cdot\nabla b + a\nabla^{2}b}
> \\[1mm]
> \ds{\nabla\,\mathrm{f}\pars{r}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\,\mathrm{f}\,'\pars{r}\,{\vec{r} \over r}}
> \\[1mm]
> \ds{\nabla\cdot\pars{c\,\vec{d}}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\nabla c\cdot\vec{d} + c\nabla\cdot\vec{d}}
> \end{array}\right.}$

\begin{align}
\nabla^{2}\pars{r^{n}\,x} & =
\nabla^{2}\pars{r^{n}}x + 2\nabla\pars{r^{n}}\cdot
\overbrace{\nabla x}^{\ds{\hat{x}}}\ +\ r^{n}\,
\overbrace{\nabla^{2}x}^{\ds{0}}
\\[3mm]
\nabla r^{n} & = n\,r^{n - 1}\,\,{\vec{r} \over r} = n\,r^{n - 2}\,\,\,\vec{r}
\\[3mm]
\nabla^{2}r^{n} & = \nabla\cdot\nabla r^{n} = n\pars{n - 2}r^{n - 3}\,\,\,
{\vec{r} \over r}\cdot\vec{r} + n\,r^{n - 2}\,\times 3 = n\pars{n + 1}r^{n - 2}
\\[3mm]
\color{#f00}{\nabla^{2}\pars{r^{n}\,x}} & =
n\pars{n + 1}r^{n - 2}\,\,x + 2nr^{n - 2}\,\,x =
\color{#f00}{n\pars{n + 3}r^{n - 2}\,\,x}
\end{align}

---

Similarly, for the $y$ and $z$:
$$
\color{#f00}{\nabla^{2}\pars{r^{n}\,\vec{r}}} =
\color{#f00}{n\pars{n + 3}r^{n - 2}\,\,\vec{r}}
$$